# Avoiding class_eval in Ruby metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to have a `return_empty_set` class method in Ruby, similar to the `attr_reader` methods. My proposed implementation is

```
class Class
  def return_empty_set *list
    list.each do |x|
      class_eval "def #{x}; Set.new; end"
    end
  end
end
```

and example usage:

```
class Foo
  return_empty_set :one
end
Foo.new.one  # returns #<Set: {}>
```

but resorting to a string seems like quite a hack. Is there a cleaner or better way to write this, perhaps avoiding `class_eval`? Or is this the best way to go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `define_method`:

```
class Module
  def return_empty_set *names
    names.each do |name|
      define_method(name){Set.new}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: excellent, thanks. and you're right, it should be under `Module`, since then I can `include` this functionality.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean, but the reason to put it under `Module` is that you can use it when inside a `Module` definition (to be included later) as well as a `Class`'.